# How to prevent displaying validation summary in Orchard?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

i am designing a module in which i planned to implement custom validation with jQuey.i have faced with a problem called `Validation Summary` that will be displayed on top of every content type **Editor** page.now i am after a way of getting rid of it.
thanks for anyone helping me.best regards.

**EDIT:**

in fact my problem is not with displaying validation summery.my original problem is as follow:

i have a ContentType called Estate which contains `1-EstatePart`  `2-AddressPart` `3-PersonalInfoPart`.when user going to register a new Estate,when user is registered (and loged in) the user information already exist in the data base thus the PersonalInfo Part shouldn't be displayed.in the PersonalInfopart view I decided to show or not show info according to a flag (associated with Model passed to view).but when i submit the form in any case PersonalInfoPart driver attempts to validate the part (which is hidden from user eyes) and displays the validation messages and my first problem is some how related to this one.

**Edit 2: What i have tried:**

i have tried to render a hidden field for ShouldDisplay property of model and in the driver i have tried to retrieve the ShouldDisplay value from the part.but PersonalInfoPart contains null properties.

my code

```
protected override DriverResult Editor(PersonalInfoPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
    {
        if (part.ShouldDisplay) //ShouldDisplay is always false (and other properties is null)
            updater.TryUpdateModel(part, Prefix, null, null);
        return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to get rid of it?

Comment: i want to implement my own validation.

Comment: Why? Why don't you plug into the existing one instead?

Comment: for answering your question i have to complete my question.i will update my question.thanks for you'r response @Le.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option may be to simply hide the part using CSS.

Comment: do you have any idea why PersonalInfoPart has null properties?

Comment: Yes: what you get from the parameter is the part as it exists in the system before the update from the form. If you've never persisted it, or if you have a problem with your persistence, because for example of a missing handler, you'll get default values, null or false, or 0, etc.

Comment: how can i send a value from client to driver showing the value of shouldDisplay?

Comment: i will mark you as answer by the way.cause i got no option other than hiding summary with css or jquery.Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: You mean using an Ajax request? You can't. Instead, you create a controller action that does.

Comment: yes it seems that i have to write a controller action and save the content using contentManager.thanks.